# What fraction of scientists are members of professional societies and/or associations?

Tags: statistics, fees, professional-association

I've been looking for some statistics that shed light into the professional society/association market of academia. Some questions I'm looking to answer in addition to the title are:

How many societies does a single scientist belong to at a given time?
For those that are members, what are the average annual fees associated with their membership(s)?
Overall, how much revenue do these societies generate from membership fees?

Comment: Note that most, perhaps all, reputable professional societies are explicitly not for profit. So, the revenue gets put back into the organization in some way - conferences and publications mostly. The officers are normally elected and not paid, though editors and other professional staff of their journals, likely are paid.

Comment: Many societies publish annual budget reports that are either online or for their membership. I would suggest you do some legwork for the finances. For example, 20 seconds on Google helped me find the ASA's budget information https://community.amstat.org/blogs/ronald-wasserstein/2014/02/10/asa-at-175-budget

Comment: Note that sometimes the motivation to join a professional society is just "it saved me money on a conference fee".

Comment: @RichardErickson Thank you. Individual society finances are informative, but a holistic academia-wide analysis is what I'm really trying to pin down. I could sift through numerous budget reports, but not be able to glean what fraction of professional scientists, globally or otherwise, subscribe to these societies.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - for some you get membership rolled into the conference registration fee (the Materials Research Society is one, there likely are others). This can help with getting reimbursements for your membership from your institution/company.

Comment: I'll guess that all you will find are anecdotal reports. I belonged to one association (ACM) and might have joined one other (IEEE), more or less sensibly. My "dues" were around $450US per year, but that included membership in a few SIGs and their journal and newsletter publications. If I'd stayed with math, there are probably two I'd have joined. I'll guess that is fairly typical, but I have no general numbers.

Comment: This is going to vary greatly by field. In mine, I only sign up to go to conferences and let it lapse if I'm not going to a conference, like most people I know. I get the impression professional societies are more important in other fields (like CS , EE, and math)

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback, I guess it seems no evident survey or meta analysis has been done that I can find. Just anecdotally, it seems that the majority of professional scientists belong to at least one, if not multiple.

Comment: Tex.SE has a [community polls](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls) meta thread; I wonder if we could have something similar here. This is going to be by no means representative of all academia, but at least it gives information. I'll suggest it on meta. EDIT: [nvm, we have it already!](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/958)

Comment: I have started a poll [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4741/958) then.

Comment: Thanks very much @FedericoPoloni! I'm really looking forward to the poll results!